# How I can hide a module in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-packaging

Imagine the folowing folders:

- mymodule

  - internal

    - `__init__.py`
    - base.py
  - expose

    - `__init__.py`
    - classes.py
  - `__init__.py`

I want that when I type in my application:

```
from mymodule import
```

Appears only the **expose** module.

What I should do to hide the module **internal** from **import** command?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: name your `internal` folder to `_internal` and put only  `expose` in root `mymodule` folders `__init__.py`

Comment: Rename to _internal don't prevents that it appears in import.
It just appears as _internal.
I want to avoid that the module appers in import.
Of course, I simplified a lot the structure in this example and change the structure is not an option in the real problem.